# Error Function In Haskell

Tags: haskell, error-handling

I have a funciton which compiles successfully in haskell.

It looks like this:

```
suffix :: Int -> String
suffix i 
   | i==0                 = "th"
   | i==1                 = "st"
   | i==2                 = "nd"
   | i==3                 = "rd"
   | i>=4 || i<=9         = "th"
   | i<0                  = error "Must be positive integer"     ----------NOT WORKING?
   | otherwise            = suffix(i `rem` 10)
```

It does not work that I can tell at least with the error line for the `i<0` guard. When I enter into GHCI and add a "-" to the a number: `suffix -5` I get the same error message I would get if I completely left this case off.

I'd like it to display my error message obviously. Hopefully someone can spot my issue. Thanks!

Comment: You could have figured out this one by properly looking at the error message: it's a _compiler error_, and `In an equation for 'it': it = suffix - 5` shows quite clearly that the problem has to do with `f -5` being parsed as `f -  5`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basic Haskell syntax weirdness.  This is the only case like it in the language.

`suffix -5` is `suffix - 5` is `(-) suffix 5`. The `-` character is treated as an infix binary operator, like all punctuation-named functions in haskell are. That is, unless there are no characters in the expression before the `-`.  The simplest way to do what you want is with `suffix (-5)`.  By enclosing it in parens, you are making it syntactically a standalone expression, which means no characters precede the `-` in the expression.

This creates its own weirdness, though, in that you can't create an operator section for subtracting a value from the input.  `(-5)` is not the section that means `\x -> x - 5`, unlike any other other binary operator in the language. It's kind of an unfortunate situation that unary negation and binary subtraction use the same symbol, because it means there have to be corner cases like this in Haskell's syntax.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `suffix -5` that is interpreted as "subtract 5 from suffix", i.e. it thinks you're trying to apply the binary operator `-` to the arguments `suffix` and `5`. Of course that won't work because you can't subtract a number from a function.

If you write `suffix (-5)`, it will work fine.

Comment: @ZAX It doesn't skip to the `otherwise` case, it goes directly into the `i>=4 || i<=9 ` case because `-5` is indeed less than 9. I imagine you meant for the `||` to be an `&&` there.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell guards match top-to-bottom. The `i < 0` condition will never match, because whenever `i` is less then zero, it will first match the `i >= 4 || i <= 9` condition above it.